# Finding Overlap counts

Tags: excel

Hi I have 2 columns (cities and members) with 5 unique cities and 100,000 members.  Some members may be assigned to multiple cities.  I would like a graph that has 6 columns and the 6 rows of the cities (with additional No City Assigned Column).  The values in the table would be the member counts. So I'm basically trying to count overlap. How can I accomplish this?

I wish it would be as simple as dragging my cities field into both columns and rows in the pivot table but I can't.

I would like it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: So are you looking to conditionally format your table where headers in row/column match?

Comment: Yes I can see the problem - the usual pattern is comparing multiple levels of 2 variables (crosstabs or pivot), but this is more like a multiple response analysis. I would struggle to do this by formula - probably looking at a VBA solution. Might be worth adding VBA tag is this is acceptable.

Comment: Would you like to add some test data to your question? It would be interesting to see what the member ID's look like and whether the city names are text or coded as numbers. I note that the question has 3 close votes at time of writing so it would be advisable to improve it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want conditional formatting:

Select the full range you want to apply the formatting to.  Then apply a rule (formula option) so that `=B$1=$A2` (assuming your have selected from B2 to some end).  The use of the fixed ("$") condition on column or row helps determine that this applies to each cell in the selected range individually.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to see basically if a member is in SD for example, what other cities is her in?  So basically looking for combination counts if that makes sense...

Comment: @pdangelo4 the above answer indicates where the labels in row 1 and column 1 (A) match, e.g. 3/3 gives an orange fill.  you can apply this to your example where TB/TB occurs and D4 would be filled with orange (color from my example).  if you were to change the label in E1 to read TB, leaving the value of TB in A4, then E4 would be filled with orange.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution. Set up a working array with one row for each distinct member, one column for each distinct city, and fill with 1's where member and city coincide. Then transfer into output array where pairs of columns in working array have been set to 1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultResponse()
Dim LastRow, LastColumn As Long
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim workArray() As Integer
Dim cityDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim memberDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim city, member As String
Dim item As Integer
Dim i, j As Long
Dim memberNo As Long
Dim cityNo As Integer
Dim outputArray() As Integer
Dim outrow, outcol, rowTotal As Integer

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row



' Make list of distinct cities

j = 0
For i = 2 To LastRow
    city = sht1.Cells(i, 2)

    If city <> "" And Not cityDict.Exists(city) Then
        j = j + 1
        cityDict.Add Key:=city, item:=j
    End If

Next i


' Make list of distinct members

j = 0
For i = 2 To LastRow
    member = sht1.Cells(i, 1)
    If member <> "" And Not memberDict.Exists(member) Then
        j = j + 1
        memberDict.Add Key:=member, item:=j
    End If
Next i


' Set up and fill array with one row for each distinct member, one column for each distinct city


ReDim workArray(1 To memberDict.Count, 0 To cityDict.Count)


For i = 2 To LastRow
    member = sht1.Cells(i, 1)
    city = sht1.Cells(i, 2)

    If city <> "" And member <> "" Then
        memberNo = memberDict(member)
        cityNo = cityDict(city)
        workArray(memberNo, cityNo) = 1
    End If
Next i



' Fill output array where pairs of columns in work array are set to 1
' outputArray(0,0) is used for members with missing city


ReDim outputArray(0 To cityDict.Count, 0 To cityDict.Count)

'First do ones with no affiliation

For i = 1 To memberDict.Count
    rowTotal = 0
    For j = 1 To cityDict.Count
        rowTotal = rowTotal + workArray(i, j)
    Next j
    If rowTotal = 0 Then outputArray(0, 0) = outputArray(0, 0) + 1
Next i

' Then do ones with affiliation

For outrow = 1 To cityDict.Count
    For outcol = 1 To cityDict.Count
        For i = 1 To memberDict.Count
            If workArray(i, outrow) = 1 And workArray(i, outcol) = 1 _
                Then outputArray(outrow, outcol) = outputArray(outrow, outcol) + 1
        Next i
    Next outcol
Next outrow

' Transfer output array into sheet

For i = 0 To cityDict.Count
    For j = 0 To cityDict.Count
        sht2.Cells(i + 2, j + 2) = outputArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

'Insert row and column headers

sht2.Cells(1, 2) = "N/C"
sht2.Cells(2, 1) = "N/C"

For i = 0 To cityDict.Count - 1
    sht2.Cells(i + 3, 1) = cityDict.Keys(i)
Next i

For j = 0 To cityDict.Count - 1
    sht2.Cells(1, j + 3) = cityDict.Keys(j)
Next j


End Sub
```

Test data

[image]

Results

[image]